# Nonisomorphic quotient rings $k[x,y]/(x^2-y^{2n+1})$ for different values of $n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I want to prove the following proposition:

> For $n\neq m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ the, $k$-algebras
>   $R_n$ and $R_m$ are non-isomorphic, where $R_n=k[x,y]/(x^2-y^{2n+1})$, at least when $k=\mathbb{C}$.

In this case being the exponent of $y$ odd, I can see that all the $R_n$ are integral domains. But also as $k[x,y]$-modules they have the same length of free resolutions, thus the same projective dimension, etc., so I'm not sure what kind of invariant should I use to prove they're not isomorphic.

I think that for $n>0$ none of the rings are UFDs and that $R_0\cong k[t]$ so that would be one case.

Comment: Not isomorphic as $k$-algebras, or not isomorphic as rings?

Comment: Unless I have missed something, don't we have that $\dim_k\overline{R_n}/R_n=n$, where $\overline{R_n}$ is the integral closure of $R_n$ in its field of fractions? Is that not an invariant of $k$-algebras?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen this is a very good observation! I agree with your assessment: $R_n\cong k[t^2,t^{2n+1}]$ by the map sending $t^2\mapsto y$ and $t^{2n+1}\mapsto x$, which has field of fractions $k(t)$ and integral closure $k[t]$, and the things in $k[t]$ missing from $k[t^2,t^{2n+1}]$ are exactly the monomials $t^a$ where $a$ is odd and less than $2n+1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's true. It's a very nice remark.

Comment: @user26857 As $k-$algebras. Of course, if you prove there is no ring isomorphism the former goes as a corollary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement about UFDs is correct, so it suffices to treat the case when $0<m<n$. Here is a very low-tech solution involving picking a basis.

First, observe that our isomorphism must take $(x,y)_{R_n}$ isomorphically on to $(x,y)_{R_m}$: the preimage of a maximal ideal is maximal, and these are the only maximal ideals so that the localization of $R_n$ and $R_m$ at them are not regular local rings. So $\varphi(x)=ax+by+p$ and $\varphi(y)=cx+dy+q$ for our putative isomorphism $\varphi:R_m\to R_n$ where $p,q\in (x,y)^2$, $a,b,c,d\in k$ and we have $ad-bc\neq 0$. On the other hand, we must have $\varphi(x^2-y^{2m+1})=0$, so $\varphi(x)^2-\varphi(y)^{2m+1}=0$, or $(ax+by+p)^2-(cx+dy+q)^{2m+1}=0$.

We can pick a basis for $R_n$ as a $k$-vector space to be $x^iy^j$ with $i<2$. Expanding out in this basis and examining the quadratic terms, we get that $b=0$ since every term in $(cx+dy+q)^{2m+1}$ has total degree at least $3$ from our assumption that $m>0$. So $a\neq 0$ and in fact we may assume it to be $1$ by scaling $x$. One may also check that $2xp+p^2$ contributes no terms of degree $2m+1$ by counting degrees.

Now let's look at what happens when we expand out $(cx+dy+q)^{2m+1}$. In our chosen basis, the terms of smallest total degree are $(2m+1)cd^{2m}xy^{2m}+d^{2m+1}y^{2m+1}$. But the only way for this to be zero is if $d=0$, since we can't apply any rewriting trickery to this element. But if $d=0$, then $ad-bc=0$, contrary to our assumption.

---

For a more high-minded proof, one may note that if we let $C_n=\operatorname{Spec} R_n$, then the blowup of $C_n$ at the origin is $C_{n-1}$, so each $C_n$ will require $n$ blowups at the unique singular point to resolve its singularities and no smaller number will do. This can be formalized via an appropriate measure of the "badness" of the singularity, but I don't exactly recall the exact setup one should use at the moment. (It's been a while - probably the Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity is the right one to use. If anyone can set me straight, I'd welcome you responding with a comment or another answer!)

Comment: Ok. At last I read it.  It looks nice.  I know I phrased the problem algebraically (since I prefer an algebraic answer), but I expected to find ideas related to blowups, at least of the varieties associated to these rings.

Comment: @Levi I'm a little confused about the phrasing of your comment: I mentioned something about blowups of the varieties associated to those rings in the final paragraph, so there is mention of "ideas related to blowups" in the answer. Anyways, if you find this answer to be acceptable, please consider [accepting it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). (I only mention this because you are a new user so you might not have experience with this feature of the website yet.)

Comment: Yes. What I meant is that even if I prefer more algebraic arguments, I expected some idea like the one you mentioned at the end, so I think the answer is better for me than what I expected originally. It's indeed an nice answer. I was planning to accept it surely if Jyrki didn't write an answer of his own but now I'm not sure he will so here it goes.

Comment: @Levi Ah, I understand. Do note that you can always decide to accept another answer later on if you so desire.

Comment: I have two questions. How is it that $(x,y)_{R_n}$ is mapped isomorphically onto $(x,y)_{R_m}$? Are you saying that the only maximal ideal containing any $(x^2-y^{2n+1})$ is $(x,y)$? I think it might be obvious but I don't really see it. The second question is, how do you make sure that the isomorphism maps $x,y$ to linear forms in this case? If I'm not mistaken I remember that you can have an isomorphism $k[x,y]\to k[x,y]$ given by $x\mapsto x, y\mapsto y\pm x^2$.

Or more in general $x\mapsto x, y\mapsto y+h(x)$ for any polynomial $h$.

Comment: @DavidMolano First, I fixed the issue with the higher order terms - you're right, that was a gap. Luckily the fix is not so hard. Second, the preimage of a maximal ideal is maximal under a map of fg $k$-algebras, and by the argument in the post, we have that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ must send $(x,y)$ to $(x,y)$ and thus they define maps $(x,y)\leftrightarrow (x,y)$, and the compositions both ways are still the identity. So $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are isomorphisms of $(x,y)_{R_n}$ with $(x,y)_{R_m}$.